# My function doesn't recognise variables that were created before it is called

Tags: python

I'm new to python and having trouble with my def's. I un-nested them because all my functions were nested in eachother, but now the function "percentified" is unable to find the variables "wins" "losses" and "ties". I'm new to python so any help is appreciated and the definition has to be a definition so that I can repeat the question if the user enters and incorrect value for an input.
Here is the code:

```
# Importing the random module
import random
import time
# The title of the game is printed
print("Rock, Paper, Scissors! - By Max Pearson")

# All user defined functions apart from code() are defined here

# Defining the first Rock Paper Scissors
def rps1():
    # Take the users input of RPS
    user_choice = input("What is your choice? Rock, Paper, or Scissors?: ")
    # Strips and lowers user input
    user_choice = user_choice.lower()
    user_choice = user_choice.strip()
    RPS = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_names = ["Computer", "Robot", "Android", "A.I", "PC", "Algorithm", "Laptop", "Alexa", "Windows"]
    computer_name = random.choice(computer_names)
    # Selecting the computer's choice
    computer_choice = random.choice(RPS)
    computer_choice = computer_choice.lower()
    computer_choice = computer_choice.strip()
    # Sets the parameters for when the user inputs Rock
    if user_choice == "rock":
        print("You have chosen Rock")
        print("{} chose... {}".format(computer_name, computer_choice.title()))
        if user_choice == computer_choice:
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif computer_choice == "paper":
            print("You lose...")
        else:
            print("You win!")
    # Sets the parameters for when the user inputs Paper
    elif user_choice == "paper":
        print("You have chosen Paper")
        print("{} chose... {}".format(computer_name, computer_choice.title()))
        if user_choice == computer_choice:
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif computer_choice == "rock":
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose...")
    # Sets the parameters for when the user inputs Scissors
    elif user_choice == "scissors":
        print("You have chosen Scissors")
        print("{} chose... {}".format(computer_name, computer_choice.title()))
        if user_choice == computer_choice:
            print("It's a tie!")
        elif computer_choice == "rock":
            print("You lose...")
        else:
            print("You win!")
    # Fallback for an invalid input
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid choice")
        rps1()

# Defining the option for a new round
def newround():
    # Take user input
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again?(Yes/No): ")
    # Stripping and lowering the variable
    playagain = playagain.strip()
    playagain = playagain.lower()
    if playagain == "yes":
        rps1()
    elif playagain == "no":
        print("Okay!")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input(Yes/No)")
        newround()

# Defining the function to turn numbers into percentages
def percentage(x):
    x = (x / num_sims) * 100
    return x

# Gives the user the option to view statistics
def percentified():
    # Take user input
    percentages = input("Would you like these results in a statistic?: ")
    percentages = percentages.lower()
    percentages = percentages.strip()
    if percentages == "yes":
        # Printing and formatting the results
        print(
            "Here are the percentages to one decimal point:\nWins = {:.1f}%\nLosses = {:.1f}%\nTies = {:.1f}%".format(
                percentage(wins), percentage(losses), percentage(ties)))
    elif percentages == "no":
        print("Okay, enjoy the results")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid choice (Yes/No)")
        percentified()

# The second gamemode of Rock Paper Scissors
def rps2():
    # Defining a list for the random choice
    RPS = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    results = []
    try:
        # Takes an input from the user, to define the number of games
        num_sims = int(input("Please enter the number of simulated games you would like: "))
        # Loops for the number the user entered
        if num_sims > 0:
            for i in range(0, num_sims):
                choice1 = random.choice(RPS)
                choice2 = random.choice(RPS)
                # Runs a check on every possible choice and adds the result to a list
                if choice1 == choice2:
                    results.append("tie")
                elif choice1 == "Rock" and choice2 == "Paper":
                    results.append("loss")
                elif choice1 == "Rock" and choice2 == "Scissors":
                    results.append("win")
                elif choice1 == "Scissors" and choice2 == "Paper":
                    results.append("win")
                elif choice1 == "Scissors" and choice2 == "Rock":
                    results.append("loss")
                elif choice1 == "Paper" and choice2 == "Rock":
                    results.append("win")
                elif choice1 == "Paper" and choice2 == "Scissors":
                    results.append("loss")
                else:
                    print("Please enter a valid choice")
                    rps2()
            # Count the results and store them in a variable
            wins = results.count("win")
            losses = results.count("loss")
            ties = results.count("tie")
            # Print the user their results
            print("Here are the results:\nWins = {}\nLosses = {}\nTies = {}".format(wins, losses, ties))
            percentified()
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid number above 0")
            rps2()
    # Fallback incase user enters a string to the integer input
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        rps2()


try:
    # Defining the entirety of the body of the code
    def code():
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # Takes the users input
        playstyle = int(input("Would you like to play RPS, or simulate a number of games? (1,2): "))
        if playstyle == 1:
            rps1()
            newround()
        # Checks if the user wants to simulate games
        elif playstyle == 2:
            rps2()
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid choice (1/2)")
            code()
    code()
# Fallback incase user enters a string to the integer input
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid choice (1/2)")
    code()
```

And here is the error:

```
NameError: name 'wins' is not defined
```

Comment: Please include full stacktrace for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`percentified` does not have access to variables defined in `rps2`. There are many ways to make `wins` available outside of the `rps2` function —, best practice would be to either pass the local variable into the `percentified` function, or use object oriented programming to share instance variables (ie: `self.wins`).

Consider brushing up on Python variable scoping.

## References

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces